# Implementing database using php files? or phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Hello I'm a super newbie for php. I started learning php from w3schools website, according to that tutorials databases for the website are created using php files.

I want to know, does it is the standard way that the web developers do for database implementation? or do they use tools like phpMyAdmin?

[Creating databases](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_create.asp)

Comment: I never manage database schema by PHP scripting. PhpMyAdmin is a good tool to do it in my opinion. Use it :)

Comment: Beside phpMyAdmin you can use SQLYog, for interacting with DB.

Comment: Many frameworks provide functionality to define your table structures easily, and a migration functionality that allows for initial creation and subsequent modification

Comment: w3schools is awefully out of date. **Do not use w3schools**. As per your specific question, there is no correct answer. A number of popular frameworks use a code first approach to database design, so in that sense, php is used to create and manage the database, but using external tools (phpmyadmin, mysql workbench etc) is also a popular technique

Comment: @steve : that particular kneejerk is a bit outdated itself, isn't it? Even http://www.w3fools.com/ is getting softer in their judgement after the updates, so I see no reason for your first sentence without any specific link / issue you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While most people would use a client to connect to the database-server and create a database and tables, it is not the only solution

If your application is starting to get bigger, you might want to 'migrate' to a new version of your database. Using a script to perfrom this migration, even if it is just a small extra table, could be the best way to make sure you can keep track of what you are doing.

This could be a php file, although creating it with a .sql script and a client (simple cli for instance) would be another method.

In the end it does not matter: you need certain sql commands send to your sql server. It might be easy to use a client (phpmyadmin is a client, just as the 'mysql' commandline client, mysql workbench, etc etc), it might be better to use a script (for advanced deployements preferable).

The page you link to is nothing more then an explanation that you *can* do this, as far as I see it does not mention you *should* do this.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to use phpMyAdmin. If you want to use a pretty graphical interface, you can also use MySQLWorkbench.